# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code I am getting the error for, after doing research I can not understand why this error keeps coming up. The line of code was working before but now this is crashing my entire project.

```
function HomePageView_GetActiveTopicParentId(id) {
    return $("#" + id).attr("egain-parent-identifier");
}
```

the second set of code

```
function HomePageController_TopicsViewChanged(id) {
sessionStorage.setItem(CURRENT_TOPIC_PARENT_ID, HomePageView_GetActiveTopicParentId(id));
sessionStorage.setItem(CURRENT_TOPIC_ID, HomePageView_GetActiveTopic(id));
$.mobile.changePage("#ViewTopicPage");
}
```

Comment: We'll need more context.

Comment: If `id` is not a `string`, but some other `object` for some reason, then `"#" + id` would result in a string like `'#[object Object]'`  and this will be an invalid selector which would result in the given error message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `id` needs to be a `string` but it is some other type of object. Where is your `HomePageController_TopicsViewChanged` function being called, and what is being passed in as the `id` parameter?